# Python enchant dictionary exist but not working

Tags: python, dictionary, pyenchant

I am using Python2.7 and trying to get enchant or aspell to come with some Danish spelling suggestions. I am using OS X Yosemite

I downloaded the `brew install aspell --with-lang-da` and that seems to work, because the dictionary seems to exist.

```
import enchant

print enchant.list_languages() #['da', 'en', 'en_CA', 'en_GB', 'en_US']
print enchant.list_dicts() #[('da', <Enchant: Aspell Provider>), ('en', <Enchant: Aspell Provider>), ('en_CA', <Enchant: Aspell Provider>), ('en_GB', <Enchant: Aspell Provider>), ('en_US', <Enchant: Aspell Provider>)]

d = enchant.request_dict("da")
print(d.suggest("motorcyke"))

d = enchant.Dict("da")
print(d.suggest("motorcyke"))
```

The problem is that no suggestion are showing up. It is like the dictionary exist but is empty.

Thanks...